# What is the difference between fascistic and fascist

Tags: differences

I've seen these words both used but not interchangeably. My guess is that fascistic refers to 'fascist in nature', e.g if a building is fascistic it is reflective of fascist ideology but not necessarily a product of a fascist regime while fascist means relating to actual instances of fascisism e.g, saying a building is fascist means it was a Nazi building or otherwise. I'm not sure though...

Comment: Have you compared their dictionary definitions?

Comment: A possible linguistic parallel is the pair 'historical' and 'historic'.